# React-native multiple actions with redux and redux thunk

Tags: react-native, redux

I am new in react, and trying to implement redux/redux-thunk for async api calling.
I have 5 sections and want to call 5 different Api's. My problem is in props state I can get only one, last executed api data, do I need to create multiple reducers or I need to combine data in one object?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isLoading: state.serviceReducer.isLoading,
    error: state.serviceReducer.error,
    data: state.serviceReducer.data,
    UserMaster: state.UserMasterReducer
  });
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        updateUserMaster: (data) => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_USER_MASTER', payload: data }),
        ApiService1:  (url,payload,id) => dispatch(ApiService(url,payload,id)),
        ApiService2:  (url,payload,id) => dispatch(ApiService(url,payload,id)),
    }
}
```

Reducer.

```
import * as Actions from '../action/ActionTypes'

const ServiceReducer = (state = { isLoading: false, error: undefined, data: {}, ActionId: undefined }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.SERVICE_PENDING:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoading: true,
                ActionId:action.id
            });
        case Actions.SERVICE_ERROR:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoading: false,
                error: action.error,
                ActionId:action.id
            });
        case Actions.SERVICE_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoading: false,
                data: action.data,
                ActionId:action.id
            }); 
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default ServiceReducer;
```

Action

```
export const serviceActionPending = (id) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.SERVICE_PENDING,
    id:id
})

export const serviceActionError = (error,id) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.SERVICE_ERROR,
    error: error,
    id:id
})

export const serviceActionSuccess = (data,id) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.SERVICE_SUCCESS,
    data: data,
    id:id
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by *My problem is in props state I can get only one, last executed api data* ??

Comment: @He I mean  mapStateToProps  'data: state.serviceReducer.data'. from componentdidmount i can call 5 apis but where to handle the data